# How to fill in the parameters of predicates by input in prolog?

Tags: prolog, crossword

I have the following code :

```
size(5).
black(1,3).
black(2,3).
black(3,2).
black(4,3).
black(5,1).
black(5,5).

words([do,ore,ma,lis,ur,as,po, so,pirus, oker,al,adam, ik]) .

:- use_module(library(lists),[nth1/3, select/3]).

crossword(Puzzle) :-
    words(WordList),
    word2chars(WordList,CharsList),
    make_empty_words(EmptyWords) ,
    fill_in(CharsList,EmptyWords),
    word2chars(Puzzle,EmptyWords).

word2chars([],[]).    
word2chars([Word|RestWords] ,[Chars|RestChars] ) :-
   atom_chars(Word,Chars),
   word2chars(RestWords,RestChars).

fill_in([],[]).
fill_in([Word|RestWords],Puzzle) :-
   select(Word,Puzzle,RestPuzzle),
   fill_in(RestWords,RestPuzzle).

make_empty_words(EmptyWords) :-
   size(Size),
   make_puzzle(Size,Puzzle),
   findall(black(I,J),black(I,J),Blacks) ,
   fillblacks(Blacks,Puzzle),
   empty_words(Puzzle,EmptyWords).

make_puzzle(Size,Puzzle) :-
   length(Puzzle,Size),
   make_lines(Puzzle,Size).

make_lines([],_).
make_lines([L|Ls],Size) :-
   length(L,Size),
   make_lines(Ls,Size).

fillblacks([],_).
fillblacks([black(I,J)|Blacks],Puzzle) :-
   nth1(I,Puzzle,LineI),
   nth1(J,LineI,black),
   fillblacks(Blacks,Puzzle).

empty_words(Puzzle,EmptyWords) :-
   empty_words(Puzzle,EmptyWords,TailEmptyWords),
   size(Size),
   transpose(Size,Puzzle,[],TransposedPuzzle),
   empty_words(TransposedPuzzle,TailEmptyWords,[] ).

empty_words([],Es,Es).
empty_words([L|Ls],Es,EsTail) :-
   empty_words_on_one_line(L,Es,Es1) ,
   empty_words(Ls,Es1,EsTail).

empty_words_on_one_line([], Tail, Tail).
empty_words_on_one_line([V1,V2|L],[[V1,V2|Vars]|R],Tail) :-
   var(V1), var(V2), !,
   more_empty(L,RestL,Vars),
   empty_words_on_one_line(RestL,R,Tail) .
empty_words_on_one_line([_| RestL],R, Tail) :-
    empty_words_on_one_line(RestL,R,Tail) .

more_empty([],[],[]).
more_empty([V|R],RestL,Vars) :-
   (  var(V) ->
      Vars = [V|RestVars],
      more_empty(R,RestL,RestVars)
   ;
      RestL = R,
      Vars = []
   ).

transpose(N,Puzzle,Acc,TransposedPuzzle) :-
   (  N == 0 ->
      TransposedPuzzle = Acc
   ;
      nth_elements(N,Puzzle,OneVert),
      M is N - 1,
      transpose(M,Puzzle,[OneVert|Acc], TransposedPuzzle)
   ).

nth_elements(_,[],[]).
nth_elements(N,[X|R],[NthX| S]) :-
   nth1(N,X,NthX),
   nth_elements(N,R,S).
```

It is used for solving a crossword like this:

[image]

The black squares places are given by default in the code but I want to find a way to give the black squares places by input when I want to query crossword.

something like this:

```
black(Y1,X1).
black(Y2,X2).
black(Y3,X3).
black(Y4,X4).
black(Y5,X5).
black(Y6,X6).

crossword(Puzzle,Y1,X1,Y2,X2,...) :-
    words(WordList),
    word2chars(WordList,CharsList),
    make_empty_words(EmptyWords,Size) ,
    fill_in(CharsList,EmptyWords),
    word2chars(Puzzle,EmptyWords).
```

Comment: The easiest way may be to use `assertz`, so you'd have `assertz(black(Y1,X1)`, etc, once `Y1` and `X1` were provided. Another way would require more rewriting of some of the code: pass in the black squares as a list argument rather than using `findall` to determine the list.

Comment: I used the second way and it's working now thanks @lurker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @lurker mentioned I tried rewriting the code and giving the black squares as input to program as below:

```
:- use_module(library(lists),[nth1/3, select/3]).

crossword(Puzzle,Size,Blacks,WordList) :-
    word2chars(WordList,CharsList),
    make_empty_words(EmptyWords,Size,Blacks) ,
    fill_in(CharsList,EmptyWords),
    word2chars(Puzzle,EmptyWords).

word2chars([],[]).
word2chars([Word|RestWords] ,[Chars|RestChars] ) :-
    atom_chars(Word,Chars),
    word2chars(RestWords,RestChars).

fill_in([],[]).
fill_in([Word|RestWords],Puzzle) :-
    select(Word,Puzzle,RestPuzzle),
    fill_in(RestWords,RestPuzzle).

make_empty_words(EmptyWords,Size,Blacks) :-
    make_puzzle(Size,Puzzle),
    fillblacks(Blacks,Puzzle),
    empty_words(Puzzle,EmptyWords).

make_puzzle(Size,Puzzle) :-
    length(Puzzle,Size),
    make_lines(Puzzle,Size).

make_lines([],_).
make_lines([L|Ls],Size) :-
    length(L,Size),
    make_lines(Ls,Size).

fillblacks([],_).   
fillblacks([black(I,J)|Blacks],Puzzle) :-
    nth1(I,Puzzle,LineI),
    nth1(J,LineI,black),
    fillblacks(Blacks,Puzzle).

empty_words(Puzzle,EmptyWords) :-
    empty_words(Puzzle,EmptyWords,TailEmptyWords),
    transpose(Size,Puzzle,[],TransposedPuzzle),
    empty_words(TransposedPuzzle,TailEmptyWords,[] ).

empty_words([],Es,Es).
empty_words([L|Ls],Es,EsTail) :-
    empty_words_on_one_line(L,Es,Es1) ,
    empty_words(Ls,Es1,EsTail).

empty_words_on_one_line([], Tail, Tail).
empty_words_on_one_line([V1,V2|L],[[V1,V2|Vars]|R],Tail) :-
    var(V1), var(V2), !,
    more_empty(L,RestL,Vars),
    empty_words_on_one_line(RestL,R,Tail) .

empty_words_on_one_line([_| RestL],R, Tail) :-
    empty_words_on_one_line(RestL,R,Tail) .

more_empty([],[],[]).
more_empty([V|R],RestL,Vars) :-
    (   var(V)
    ->  Vars = [V|RestVars],
        more_empty(R,RestL,RestVars)
    ;   RestL = R,
        Vars = []
    ).

transpose(N,Puzzle,Acc,TransposedPuzzle) :-
    (   N == 0
    ->  TransposedPuzzle = Acc
    ;   nth_elements(N,Puzzle,OneVert),
        M is N - 1,
        transpose(M,Puzzle,[OneVert|Acc], TransposedPuzzle)
    ).

nth_elements(_,[],[]).
nth_elements(N,[X|R],[NthX| S]) :-
    nth1(N,X,NthX),
    nth_elements(N,R,S).
```

now by the following input the code returns the answer to the puzzle:

```
crossword(Puzzle,5,[black(1,3),black(2,3),black(3,2),black(4,3),
black(5,1),black(5,5)],[do,ore,ma,lis,ur,as,pu, so,pirus, uker,al,adam, ik]).
```

And the output will be:

```
Puzzle = [as,pu,do,ik,ore,ma,ur,lis,adam,so,al,pirus,uker]
```

Comment: Good job (+1). Also, now that you pass the size in as an argument, the `size(X).` clause doesn't do anything, so it can be eliminated.

Comment: You are right @lurker , I removed it from the code.Thanks for mentioning it.

Answer (score 2):

Very nice, +1 for solving it yourself.

In addition, I would like to show you how to use DCGs to obtain predicates with fewer arguments for `empty_words/2` and its related predicates, which are therefore easier to understand. Further, `transpose/2` is already available as a library predicate in SICStus Prolog and SWI (see its source code if you are interested in how it is implemented), so I use that instead. Notice that `size/1` is no longer necessary.

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)). % for transpose/2 in SWI-Prolog

empty_words(Puzzle,EmptyWords) :-
    phrase(empty_words(Puzzle), EmptyWords, RestEmptyWords),
    transpose(Puzzle, TransposedPuzzle),
    phrase(empty_words(TransposedPuzzle), RestEmptyWords).

empty_words([])     --> [].
empty_words([L|Ls]) --> empty_words_on_one_line(L), empty_words(Ls).

empty_words_on_one_line([]) --> [].
empty_words_on_one_line([V1,V2|Ls0]) -->
    { var(V1), var(V2) }, !,
    [[V1,V2|Vars]],
    { more_empty(Ls0, Ls, Vars) },
    empty_words_on_one_line(Ls) .
empty_words_on_one_line([_|Ls]) --> empty_words_on_one_line(Ls).
```

The other predicates remain unchanged.

Your `fill_in/2` is available as `permutation/2`.

`maplist/2` can help you in other places, like:

```
maplist(length_list(Size), Puzzle)
```

to replace `make_lines/2` with a short definition of `length_list/2` that I leave as a simple exercise.